# How to find an object size from its image using OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv

From an image of a given object lets say a mouse, how to find its length width and height using OpenCV in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the focal length and sensor height of the camera you can use the equation

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

Refer this [link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo) for more information.

For far distance object you can use the equation by *THE RULE OF 57*

```
Distance of object= (Size of object * 360)/(2 * 3.14 * Angular size in degree)
```

Refer this [link](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/webscope/activities/pdfs/measureSize.PDF) for more info.

And finally you can do modeling. 
That is first take a picture with reference object  and find  pixel to distance ratio. From next time use this ratio to measure distance.

Hope these helpful....

Comment: would you know a way or a reference to how to find pixel to distance ratio by first taking picture with a reference object? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks friend.. let me try it..

Comment: @Unheilig You can use a DVD  as reference object, and it's radius always 12cm, then use hough-circle to detect the DVD or  manually draw the circle around DVD. Now you know the DVD dimension in pixel and centimeter, then find the ratio and all the object in same distance will keep this ratio.

Comment: @Haris Thanks for reply. And I suppose the above way works not just with openCV? Let say with android or iOS?

Comment: @Unheilig Yes you can create android application which takes the picture with DVD and then use Hough-Circle to detect DVD, do the pixel to distance conversion and finally draw a line above the object you want to measure at same distance of the DVD.